# Reactivejs autocomplete forking pipeline

Tags: rxjs

Im going through some Reactivejs tutorial, and i'm implementing autocomplete with rx.js.

It looks great, but i wonder how to achieve some functionality.
Look at this code:

```
const $title = $('#title'); // input element
const $results = $('#result');

Rx.Observable.fromEvent($title, 'keyup')
    .map(event => event.target.value.trim())
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .debounceTime(500)
    .switchMap(getItems) // getItems sends request for result based on input value and returns promise
    .subscribe(items => {
        $results.empty();
        $results.append(items.map(record => $('<li> /').text(record)));
    });
```

This works great, I can get updated list on input value change.
But in case user has cleared input completely, I want to prevent from request to be sent.
I can achieve it using filter:

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent($title, 'keyup')
    .map(event => event.target.value.trim())
    .filter(query => query.length > 0)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .debounceTime(500)
    .switchMap(getItems)
    .subscribe(items => {
        $results.empty();
        $results.append(items.map(record => $('<li> /').text(record)));
    });
```

but in case user has cleared this input I don't want to send additional request and I want load default list of items.

How can i achieve that?

Is there a way to capture new entry in observable collection and in case it is empty string disrupt processing pipe but somehow still subscribe for it?:

```
 Rx.Observable.fromEvent($title, 'keyup')
        .map(event => event.target.value.trim())

        // CHECK IF INPUT VALUE IS EMPTY STRING, NAD IF IT IS
        // PREVENT PIPELINE STEPS BELOW FROM BEING PROCESSED.
        // ALSO SHOW DEFAULT LIST ITEMS

        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .debounceTime(500)
        .switchMap(getItems)
        .subscribe(items => {
            $results.empty();
            $results.append(items.map(record => $('<li> /').text(record)));
        });
```

I've tried implementing it this way:

```
const query$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($title, 'keyup')
    .map(event => event.target.value.trim());

query$
    .filter(query => query.length > 0)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .debounceTime(500)
    .switchMap(getItems)
    .subscribe(items => {
        $results.empty();
        $results.append(items.map(record => $('<li> /').text(record)));
    });

query$.subscribe(query => {
    if (!query.length) {
        $results.text('default list'); // this list will still be overwritten with last fetch result
    }
});
```

But last response for query still calls my subscribe listener and populates list with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most straightforward solution is:

```ts
Rx.Observable.fromEvent($title, 'keyup')
    .map(event => event.target.value.trim())
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .debounceTime(500)
    .switchMap((search) => {
        if(!search) return Rx.Observable.of(null);

        return getItems(search);
    })
    .subscribe(items => {
        $results.empty();
        if (items == null) {
            $results.text('default list');
        } else {
            $results.append(items.map(record => $('<li> /').text(record)));
        }
    });
```

**Explanation**

All magic is in `switchMap` operator. Basically it substitutes source observable with the one provided by callback. When next event reaches `switchMap` it completes previously created observable and creates new one.

In your case it used to fire server request for user's input and to cancel previous request if user changes input while it [request] is still going.

The problem with your implementation is that `switchMap` knows nothing about empty inputs. Chain of events:

- user presses 'a'

  - first stream debounces then starts loading items from a server
  - second stream ignores event
- user clears the input

  - first stream filters out event with `filter` (event doesn't reach `switchMap`)
  - second stream shows default items
- server responses with items and first stream's subscribe logic is called. Thus default items are overwritten.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I wonder why the last response doesn't call my subscribe listener. Can you demistify it?

Comment: @user2359820, I have updated the answer. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one common source observable, share it and after that create two subscription - one for empty and one for not empty result. You can resume the same effect function that invoked in subscribe. It will removes ifs in the code and make it more readable and reusable.

Something like that:

```
let input = document.getElementById('inp');
let obs$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input, 'keyup')
  .map(event => event.target.value.trim())
  .share();

function doEffect(result) {
  console.log(result)
}

obs$
  .filter(query => query.length > 0)
  .switchMap(x=>Rx.Observable.of([x.toUpperCase(), x.toUpperCase()]))
  .subscribe(x=>doEffect(x))

obs$
  .filter(query => query.length === 0)
  .mapTo([])
  .subscribe(x=>doSideEffect(x))
```

Comment: Did you check your solution? It has the same flaw as OP's one - `last response for query still calls my subscribe listener and populates list with the results`

Comment: yes. i did. you can add your default list logic instead of  .mapTo([])

Comment: [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/ricacaqexe/edit?js,output) type 'aa' (wait for response) and then clear it with backspace.